# OpenCL program using too much memory

Tags: c, arrays, memory, opencl

I have successfully implemented a Digital Down Converter using OpenCL. When implementing the interpolation part, I can only set a maximum factor of 146. Any more causes the program to crash and an error code of `CL_INVALID_MEM_OBJECT -38` is thrown.

For those who don't know, interpolation is a method of constructing new data points within the range of known data points. The DDC, or digital down converter, is used to increase or decrease the sampling rate all while trying to reconstruct data points by using a reconstruction filter.

Note that the file I am using is a 1.75Mb wav file as an input. It is sampled at 44100 and my goal is to make it sampled at 48000 (blue ray quality). This results in a Interpolation/Decimate factor of 160/147. But any interpolation factor over 146 crashes the drivers and the program and error for -38 is thrown as shown above.

I think the problem lies where I create the `cl_mem` buffers. I have about 7 and here are how they are initialised and used. Assume P is 3 and Q is 2 while num_items is 918222 samples:

```
input = clCreateBuffer(
    context,
    CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,
    num_items * sizeof(float),
    NULL,
    &status);

output = clCreateBuffer(
    context,
    CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY,
    num_items * P * sizeof(float),
    NULL,
    &status);

//Lowpass kernel parameters
inputForLowpass = clCreateBuffer(
    context,
    CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,
    num_items * P * sizeof(float),
    NULL,
    &status);

outputFromLowpass = clCreateBuffer(
    context,
    CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,
    num_items * P * sizeof(float),
    NULL,
    &status);

//Decimate kernel parameters
inputForDecimate = clCreateBuffer(
    context,
    CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,
    num_items * P * sizeof(float),
    NULL,
    &status);

outputFromDecimate = clCreateBuffer(
    context,
    CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,
    (int)(num_items * (P*1.0 / Q) * sizeof(float)),
    NULL,
    &status);

//numOfCoefficients for number of taps
coeff = clCreateBuffer(
    context,
    CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,
    numOfCoefficients * sizeof(float),
    NULL,
    &status);
```

I used the memory debugger in Visual Studio to find that the program uses 602Mb (for interpolation factor of 160 before it crashes. It used around 120Mb for a factor of 3, still alot!) How can I bring this down? Am I using the buffers in an incorrect manner?

On top of this, I have three other memory allocations in the host code. The 'Array' simply holds the values in the wav file while OutputData and OutputData2 store values from the filtered input and decimated input respectively.

```
Array = (float*)malloc(num_items * sizeof(float));
OutputData = (float*)malloc(num_items * P * sizeof(float));
OutputData2 = (float*)malloc((int)(num_items * (P*1.0 / Q) * sizeof(float)));
```

The following is an image of the memory usage in Visual studio when P=3 (array gets increased by a size of 3).

[image]

Here is one of the writeBuffers where I get the -38 code.

```
status = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(
    cmdQueue,
    inputForLowpass,
    CL_FALSE,
    0,
    num_items * P * sizeof(float),
    OutputData,
    0,
    NULL,
    NULL);
printf("Input enqueueWriteBuffer for Lowpass Kernel status: %i \n", status);
```

Here is the lowpass kernel:

```
__kernel void lowpass(__global float *Array, __global float *coefficients, __global float *Output, __const int numOfCoefficients) {

    int globalId = get_global_id(0); 
    float sum=0.0f;
    int min_i= max((numOfCoefficients-1),globalId)-(numOfCoefficients-1);
    int max_i= min_i+numOfCoefficients;
    for (int i=min_i; i< max_i; i++)
    {
        sum +=Array[i]*coefficients[globalId-i];    
    }
    //sum = min(., (0.999969482421875));
    //sum = max(sum, -1.0f);
    Output[globalId]=sum;
```

}

**EDIT**
Error occurs because the buffer size I allocate has over 512Mb of memory being used. That is the maximum size of a buffer that I can have. In order to fix this issue, I have to implement some sort of memory management system into my code. Perhaps by using an 8Mb buffer at a time.

Comment: Can you show us where you write to those buffers, and where you call your kernel? (and cleanup code might be a good idea too) `CL_INVALID_MEM_OBJECT` I don't think is thrown by `clCreateBuffer`.

Comment: @JavaProphet I have added the writeBuffer as well as the kernel. It also throws the same error for the decimate kernel. I'll try to add the log message it outputs when that error occurs aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Your memory objects are not explicitly backed by anything, and that might be your issue. I'd recommend adding a flag from

https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateBuffer.html

such as `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR`, `CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR`, or `CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR`, then specifying a host pointer. If you use `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR`, the buffer will not be allocated again on the host if it will be in host memory, perhaps helping your issue if it's just memory usage.

Comment: So I tried your approach with `CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR` and it seemed the make the performance alot slower. I first tried it for the input buffer and noticed the Interpolate kernel jumped by 13ms. Then when i tried the same for the output buffer, the program crashed.  The interpolate kernel is just a simple kernel adds an element at every 'nth' position in the array from a given input array.

Comment: @VedhaR I didn't recommend `CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR`, but `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR`.

Comment: sorry that's what I mean, i used 'CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR', I just copied it wrong into the box here

Comment: @VedhaR Despite the performance loss, did it work with larger sample sets?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I've been away for a while. Anyways, it did not work. After further investigation, I am getting an Array out of bounds exception. I think this isn't a memory issue, but rather an indexing one. I am going to trace my code a bit better and see where the crash is occurring.

Comment: I think i have found the issue. With another debugging tool, it crashed on clCreateBuffer. The buffer is passing the maximum CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE which is 512Mb. One of the buffers i declare is actually trying to use 514.5Mb, which could be the reason it crashes. Going to try and use two separate buffers to see if it fixes the issue.